# Best way to set a cookie in php that can be authenticated in R?

Tags: php, r, security, cookies, shiny

This is a broad question, and I've done a ton of research on this over the last few weeks. However, I haven't really found a good secure solution for this. I'm working on a site that uses WordPress/PHP, but has an R Shiny app that is used under the same domain. This is a membership site, and the R Shiny app needs to be able to identify whether a logged in user (via WordPress) should have access to the app.  I assume this is a common task for other languages, but R Shiny is quite limited in terms of its web development abilities. The only way I've really found to identify whether access should be granted is via cookies. However, it's been a struggle to find a encryption or security type approach that will work between both PHP and R.

My current thought is that when the `setcookie` function is run at login/initiation, a separate key could be passed to the server that would then be loaded and authenticated in the R Shiny app (server-side) in addition to checking a corresponding cookie. However, I have much more experience with R as opposed to PHP, so I'm not sure if this would work (especially since this "key" would need to be removed at logout). Does anyone know if there is a recommended or "best" way to authenticate access like this between two languages/programs? Specifically re: R's limited ability. Or maybe there are resources out there that I can research? I've already spent a good deal of time working with libsodium and openssl, which both have (limited) functions in R, but no luck w/ a server authentication approach like this.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the server-side, you can get access to the `session$request` object.

This object will contain the full http request, including the headers (side note: as it is set via an HTTP GET request, you can use `httpOnly`).

There are a lot of things there:

```
names(session$request)
 [1] "SERVER_NAME"                   "SERVER_PORT"                   "rook.url_scheme"               "REQUEST_METHOD"                "rook.version"                 
 [6] "rook.errors"                   "HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_EXTENSIONS" "HTTP_USER_AGENT"               "HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_VERSION"    "HTTP_CONNECTION"              
[11] "SCRIPT_NAME"                   "HTTP_ORIGIN"                   "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"          "rook.input"                    "REMOTE_PORT"                  
[16] "HTTP_COOKIE"                   "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"          "HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY"        "HTTP_UPGRADE"                  "httpuv.version"               
[21] "HTTP_HOST"                     "HEADERS"                       "PATH_INFO"                     "QUERY_STRING"                  "REMOTE_ADDR"                  
[26] "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"            "HTTP_PRAGMA"
```

What interests you is at

```
> session$request$HTTP_COOKIE
[1] "plop=this"
```

In case you need it, I wrote a small function to parse cookie strings [here](https://github.com/ColinFay/brochure/blob/main/R/cookie.R#L10).

So the idea would be to do a redirect with PHP the will `Set-cookie` in the header, then inside the `{shiny}` session, parse the cookie string and then check that this cookie is valid.

If you are using a JWT, you can have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jose/vignettes/jwt.html

Ps: I've done that using NodeJS so far, so I'm not exactly sure how it works with PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will look into this later tonight. I've read a little bit about sessions over the last few weeks. So, in this case, will a user have to login each time they visit the site for the info to be stored and identified for access purposes? From what I gather, session information clears when the session is closed. Is that right?

Comment: The `session` object is new every time you connect to a shiny app. But that's true for every other app builder: whenever you connect to a NodeJS app for example, as the communication is stateless, you don't have any session identifier from the server side. That's why you need a form of cookie: a cookie is stored in the browser, so the R session has nothing to do with it, but can use it to re-identify the user if needed.

Comment: In this case, I'm mostly trying to ensure 1.) someone couldn't just create or copy an existing cookie to get around access restrictions and 2.) they do not need to login each time they visit the site. Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong, but would this session approach accomplish this?